# Не могу разобраться с getStaticProps

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

В корне каталога создаю папку users в ней создаю page.tsx

```
const UserList = () => {
  return <div>UserList</div>;
};

export default UserList;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

В итоге ничего не выводится а data undefined.
Next последняя версия
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо в папку `pages` класть, а её в корень. Т.е. `root → pages → users → page.tsx`.

Comment: Если кладу в папку pages в итоге не могу на страницу зайти ,все равно данных нет www.localhost:3000/users